# zsh: command not found: python | I just want my python files to run again

Tags: python, django, path, zsh

I was messing around with Django for a task on my bootcamp and now my VSCode won't run my python files using the run button in the top right.
Here's what I see in my IDE:

```
garethmorton@MacBook-Pro T28 2D Lists % python -u "/Users/garethmorton/VSCode Python/T28 2D Lists/minesweeper.py"
zsh: command not found: python
garethmorton@MacBook-Pro T28 2D Lists %
```

If I right click and select run Python file in terminal my code runs and I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/garethmorton/VSCode Python/T28 2D Lists/minesweeper.py"
garethmorton@MacBook-Pro T28 2D Lists % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/garethmorton/VSCode Python/T28 2D Lists/minesweeper.py"
```

How do I fix the file path so that I can just run the code like I used to?

thanks

I have tried a few things I was told to do but to be honest I don't understand it enough to explain. I would love to just be able to delete the IDE and reinstall. By the way I'm on mac so I'm not sure if that makes things more complicated

I definitely have the python extension installed.. everything should be installed and ready because ive been running python code for months on my bootcamp

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it with `python3` instead of `python` as follows:

```
python3 "/Users/garethmorton/VSCode Python/T28 2D Lists/minesweeper.py"
```

Comment: How do i do that?